# Assigning a for loop to do multiple jobs on individual column R

Tags: r, for-loop

Here is my data in tab delimited txt file:

https://drive.google.com/open?id=1SfqY8FBnpLCs8TKySK_HYR6kzWChLRjb

Is there a way to make a for loop for the following code:

```
ka1 <- dput(as.numeric(na.omit(data$Ka1)))

ka2 <- dput(as.numeric(na.omit(data$Ka2)))

ka3 <- dput(as.numeric(na.omit(data$Ka3)))

reference <- dput(as.numeric(na.omit(data$Reference)))

ks1 <- dput(as.numeric(na.omit(data$Ks1)))

ks2 <- dput(as.numeric(na.omit(data$Ks2)))

ks3 <- dput(as.numeric(na.omit(data$Ks3)))
```

I am trying to place each individual column of the df into a list assigned to a vector:

```
> Reference
[1] 1401

> Ka1
[1]  57 108 333 510
```

I Tried the following, but I do not understand the entire process.

```
for (i in data) {
  names(data) <- deput(as.numeric(na.omit(data$i)))
}
```

Comment: Please share a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example/5963610#5963610) of your data.

Comment: You'r example data can not be coerced to data.frame due to different number of rows. Also it's very unclear of what your desired result is or what you attempt to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To extract the columns of you data into a list you can do the following:

```
data_list <- lapply(data, function(x) as.numeric(na.omit(x)))

data_list[["Ka1"]]
[1]  57 108 333 510
```

This is a short and faster version of the following `for` loop:

```
data_list <- vector(length = ncol(data), mode = "list")
names(data_list) <- names(data)

for (i in names(data)) {
  data_list[[i]] <- as.numeric(na.omit(data[[i]]))
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this:

```
for(var in names(data)) {
    data[[var]] <- dput(as.numeric(na.omit(data[[var]])))
}
```